# sound level rms

Tags: java, audio

I have found some code to calculate microphone sound level (RMS):

```
public int calculateRMSLevel(byte[] audioData) {
    // audioData might be buffered data read from a data line
    long lSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < audioData.length; i++) {
        lSum = lSum + audioData[i];
    }

    double dAvg = lSum / audioData.length;

    double sumMeanSquare = 0d;
    for (int j = 0; j < audioData.length; j++) {
        sumMeanSquare = sumMeanSquare + Math.pow(audioData[j] - dAvg, 2d);
    }

    double averageMeanSquare = sumMeanSquare / audioData.length;
    return (int) (Math.pow(averageMeanSquare, 0.5d) + 0.5);
}
```

But it only works for the following audio format:

```
private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;

    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;

    int channels = 1;

    boolean signed = true;

    boolean bigEndian = true;

    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
            bigEndian);
}
```

How to extend the code so it can work with different bitness? If I change the bitness to 16 it returns values of around 50 when silence where for 8 bits it returns 1 or 2.Also I would like to graph the sound levels on a graph, how are the sound level values related to time?

Comment: It's quite old question, but I ran into the same problem - RMS for me is always around 50. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The sample rate doesn't matter, but the bit depth, endianness, and, in a different way, number of channels, do matter.

To see why, you must simply notice that the function in question takes a byte array as an argument and processes each value from that array individually. The byte datatype is an 8-bit value. If you want something that works with 16-bit values, you need to use a different datatype (short) or convert to that from bytes.

Once you do that, you will still get different values for 16 bits vs 8 bit because the range is different: 8 bit goes from -128 to +127 and 16 bit goes from -32768 to +32767, but they are both measuring the same thing, meaning they scaling the same real-word values to different represented values.

As for sound-levels and their relationship to time.... well it depends on your sample rate and the size of the arrays going into this function. For example, if your samplerate is 8kHz and you have 2048 samples per buffer, then your function is going to be called 8000/2048 or about 3.9 times per second, meaning your results are coming in at that rate (every 256 milliseconds).

Comment: SR = 8000 mhz
buffer size = 2048

Comment: I doubt your sample rate is 8000 mhz! It is surely 8000 Hz or 8 kHz. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always scale your inputs to the same min-max range to get similar results from different formats.

As for sound level w.r.t. time, there isn't any relation other than samples being apart from each other by 1/SampleRate(in Hz) seconds.